# Problemas com opacity do CSS

Tags: css

Estou tentando colocar uma imagem de modo que fique semelhante a esta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém não é o que acontece, mas observem como está minha pagina;

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="apresentacao">
            <div id="frase1">
                Bem vindo ao Agendador de salas
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="apresentacao2">
            Fique atento as regras para agenda as salas para reunião.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Vejam como está meu CSS;

```
#frase1{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color:#000000; 

}
```

Era para o plano de fundo ter ficado preto. Como faço para efetuar o que preciso?

tentei fazer as alterações sugeridas, porém não tive sucesso;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```css
#conteudo{
        background:url(http://www.semprefamilia.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/SJC_prefeitura-1180x472.jpg) no-repeat;
        width:100%;
        min-height:400px;
    }
    #apresentacao{
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.40);
        padding:10px;
        position: relative;
        width:80%;
    }
    
    #apresentacao .frases {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    color:#FFF;
    background: #000;
    padding:5px;
    border: 1px solid #FFF;
    
    }
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="apresentacao">
            <h1 class="frases" >Bem vindo ao Agendador de salas</h1>
            <h2 class="frases">Fique atento as regras para agenda as
                salas para reunião.
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note que coloquei uma classe frase nos textos para facilitar a formatação, agora você pode atacar o tamanho da font direto no elemento h1 e h2. como por exemplo:

```
#apresentacao h1{
   font-size:1em; 
   font-family: Arial,
}

#apresentacao h2{
   font-size:0.75em; 
   font-family: Arial,
}
```

Comment: Foi o link da home do jsfiddle, amigo!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/08rhp35z/

Comment: Comentei apenas pra lembrar do engano, parabéns pela resposta! +1

Comment: esse pegou, mas agora como faço para aumentar a fonte da letra?

Comment: pode usar o font-size:1em por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Podemos utilizar [css3](/questions/tagged/css3), onde o `0.5` abaixo representa a transparência da cor.

```css
#frase1{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: RGBA(0,0,0,0.5); 

}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="apresentacao">
            <div id="frase1">
                Bem vindo ao Agendador de salas
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="apresentacao2">
            Fique atento as regras para agenda as salas para reunião.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que sua pergunta não tenha relação com opacidade, visto que você cita o termo apenas no título. Assumo, também, que ela seja sobre a estilização do texto. Portanto, aí vai a minha resposta com base nessa premissas:

Evite usar a mesma `tag` para definições de tamanho e de estilo de texto, isso tem efeitos indesejados. Caso você queira estilizar o texto apenas (i.e., mudar a cor de fundo e a cor do próprio texto), eu sugiro a utilização do `<span>`. Veja:

```css
#frase1{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

#frase1 span{
    background-color:#000000; 
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="conteudo">
        <div id="apresentacao">
            <div id="frase1">
              <span>Bem vindo ao Agendador de salas</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="apresentacao2">
            <span>Fique atento as regras para agenda as salas para reunião.</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

No `CSS` eu separei o que é relacionado ao posicionamento do que é relacionado à estilização do texto. Assim, `#frase1` fica responsável por posicionar a sua frase onde você quiser, enquanto `#frase1 span` contém as regras de cor e afins. Veja também que adicionei a cor branca, pra alcançar o efeito desejado.